# EVGA Nvidia GT 240 intermittently stops working

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, nvidia-graphics-card

My EVGA Nvidia GT 240 video card stops working on both windows-7 and windows xp. When it stops, the screen is disturbed and computer halts. Additionally, a continuous sound comes from speaker. It doesn't happen when I'm gaming, but it happens when I try to play youtube videos or audio. I can't exactly pin down a cause.

I have latest driver installed from nvidea site. Any help?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is most often caused by not having the video card connected to the PSU. In the below photo, top-left is where the PSU connection would go, so make sure that it is there and seated correctly, then make sure your PSU is over 300W, which is the minimum recommended for this video card.

[image]

Comment: Check out my model EVGA GT-240, It does not have any point to connect with PSU.

Comment: So you have the superclocked version of the EVGA GT 240? I ask this, because according to the [EVGA website](http://www.evga.com/products/prodlist.asp?family=GeForce+200+Series+Family), they have 3 versions of the 240. This one doesn't seem to have the 4-pin connector socket at the top-right, but the other two do have them. So without saying your wrong, can you be sure that you have in fact got the superclocked version? Otherwise, my initial answer still might be right and you could have a working video card!

Comment: I have this one http://www.evga.com/products/enlarge.asp?pn=01G-P3-1246-LR&I=1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but my cause was Microsoft Security Essentials.

It was the behavior monitoring. I turned it off, then problem went away.

What is really strange, is that I re-installed MSE, and it still isn't doing that error, even though the behavior monitor is turned on. My GPU isn't exactly the same model though. mine gives me random FPS drops now.

Answer (score 0):

If the video card requires power, and it is not hooked up, then the machine will beep at you. I don't think this is a power issue, possibly just a defective card. Do you have another video card to test with? Also try testing your memory. If you have a windows 7 install DVD, there is memory diagnostics on that disk. Boot from the DVD and you should get an option for memory diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem for the GT 240. I even have one and it is defective. However, it will most likely help to get a better thermal compound. You can easily find it at `tigerdirect.ca` or `tigerdirect.com` and it will increase performance if you don't have these issues.